# SETFACL to not go out of /home

Tags: permissions, acl, shared-folders

So I've been testing ACL's in Linux and they work as intended. I have, for example, this folder where I've stablished permissions for users belonging to the gruop `share`. So far, so good...

```
lucas@lucas:/$ getfacl testAcl/
# file: testAcl/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:share:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:share:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

This works fine. Once the ACL has been set, users can or cannot go into the specified folder, as per their group membership.

But I'm interested in something a little different: users usually log into the server, and they land in their `/home/user` folder. How can I set up an ACL so users can't leave the `/home` directory but also be able to go deeper inside `/home/share`, for example?

I've though about two options so far:

- All users belonging to group `adm` CAN leave /home, or ...
- All users belonging to group `share` CANNOT leave /home.

How can I set that up using `setfacl`?

Comment: Leaving `/home` is as simple as `cd /`. You really can't deny a user access to everything above some directory, since that would mean they can't run programs that reside in `/usr/bin`. The programs need access to various files, like libraries, configuration files, etc.

Comment: yeah, I see your point. But this server, its only purpose, it's a file server. I really don't need users to run anything. I only want them to use is as storage ... With that in mind, I don't think that your point, in this case, would be a problem ...

Comment: Ok, then the users don't need shell access at all. You should probably run some file sharing software like NFS or Samba, and use the mechanisms provided by them to restrict access to the appropriate directories.